# Replace capture group with line number (sed? awk? python?)

Tags: python, regex

I have source code in which I would like to insert filename:linenumber into various logging statements, such as:

```
logger.e("", "an error happened");
```

The first string literal needs to be replaced. The string literal might not be blank. If I'm editing a file on which I've already run my replacement the line might be:

```
logger.e("filename:123", "an error happened, this is the line number the last time I edited the file.")
```

The plan is to create a text processor as part of my build pipeline that does a search-and-replace for logging statements and inserts filename:linenumber. I originally planned to use awk, but having beaten myself up trying to get that to work will be content with using any suitable tool.

I have created a regex intending to capture the text to be replaced in a capture group:

```
logger\.[tdiwe]\("(.*?)"
```

This should (I think) match text starting with 'logger', then a dot, then any of t, d, i, w, or e (trace/debug/info/warn/error), then a left paren, then a double-quote, then zero or more characters, then a double-quote. I believe, but am not 100% certain, that the `"(.*?)"` part of the regex puts the characters between the first set of double quotes into a capture group.

However, after poking at this in various tools, it seems that extracting capture groups is straightforward, but replacing them is not.

I did get some Python code to do what I want but this seems excessive and I've spent enough time banging at this problem that I want someone to show me the easier way.

```
with open(infilename) as infile:
        with open(outfilename, "w") as outfile:
            linenumber = 1
            for line in infile:
                rslt = re.search(r'logger\.[tdiwe]\("([^"]*)', line)
                if rslt:
                    outfile.write(line[:rslt.span(1)[0]] + f"filename:{str(linenumber)}" + line[rslt.span(1)[1]:])
                else:
                    outfile.write(line)

                linenumber += 1
```

Comment: What is the language you are trying to parse? Python?

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach was close. In your situation though, it's better to capture into group everything except what you want to replaces.

So you can use `(logger\.[tdiwe]\(")[^"]*` and replacement string `\1filename:123`.

Your code will look something like this:

```py
import re
infilename = 'myinputfile'
outfilename = 'myoutputfile'

myregex = re.compile(r'(logger\.[tdiwe]\(")[^"]*')

with open(infilename) as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    
    for line_number, line in enumerate(lines):
        lines[line_number] = myregex.sub(r'\1' + f'{infilename}:{str(line_number+1)}', line)

    with open(outfilename, "w") as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(lines)
```

Demo online [here](https://ideone.com/XNPkTi).